# Mistake in Count Even Number List?

Tags: python

Can someone point out to me why the list is not returning the list I input with the amount of Even numbers in the list?

> ```
> import sys
> import random
>
> def count_even(num_list):
>   num_list = [7, 65, 1337, 8, -2, 24, 6, 67, 54, 36, 25, 1, 42, 9, 138, 4356, 6]
>   count_even = 0
>   for num in num_list:
>       if num % 2 == 0:
>           count_even += 1
>   return num_list
>
>
>
> def main(argv):
>
>   error_code = 0
>
>   num_list = [7, 65, 1337, 8, -2, 24, 6, 67, 54, 36, 25, 1, 42, 9, 138, 4356, 6]
>   print(count_even(num_list))
>
>
>   return error_code
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>   error_code = main(sys.argv[1:])
>   print('[+] Terminated with code: ' + str(error_code))
>   sys.exit(error_code)
> ```

Comment: You need to return `count_even` rather than `num_list` from function `count_even`. Also it's probably confusing to give the variable name the same name as the function, though it should still work.

Comment: You know, what I love but hate about coding and programming, sometimes, all it takes is a one or two misplaced inputs and the whole thing goes to shit. I cant believe I didnt think of that and I typed up the damn thing! What is wrong with me?? Thank you for pointing that out cause I think I let the frustration get to me and that is probably why I didnt see or think of that...

Comment: Blind spots happen to all of us, and a fresh pair of eyes is always useful. But I would suggest in general not giving your variables the same name as the enclosing function, as one day you will want to write a recursive function (i.e. one which calls itself) and then it won't work if you have reassigned the function name to refer to a local variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

in def count_even, you're returning the array, instead of count of even numbers which is count_even. Like @alaniwi mentioned, replace 'return num_list' with 'return count_even'.

Comment: Yeah I did not see or consider that. Probably due to the sheer frustration I was going through. I'm sure you can relate as a budding engineer. Thank you guys I appreciate the help.

Comment: definitely, best of luck to us both!